# convert a .fbx model to threejs with textures

Tags: export, texture-baking, optimization

I have an insanely detailed .fbx model that I need to optimize and export to threejs. It comes with a lot of texture files which I need too bake into one image to go with the threejs model. Unfortunately I can't upload the model as it is proprietary. I need some direction though, I am completely lost at the moment.

Basically three points i would like an answer to:

-make a single image from a whole gamut of textures.

-convert a .fbx model to threejs, with aforementioned texture.

-optimise it all to run with limited resources.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not reall my area of expertise but I'd say you probably need to import your FBX model into Blender, and then manually recreate all materials with the corresponding textures for a target render engine of your choice (say Cycles, Internal, or any other you desire). Then unwrap your model in a new UV Map, encompassing all faces of your model so you can bake all materials into a single new big texture. Geometry simplification will probably have to be done by hand or with the help of a *Decimate* modifier where possible.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so thanks to Duarte for the direction. Here's what I ended up doing for anyone having a similar issue.

I started by importing the FBX into blender, then joined all the objects so I had a single large object.

Then I added a decimate modifier, made a copy of the object and removed all materials from the copy, after which I added a new blank material.

To end up with a single texture I made a new blank image in the UV Editor (size 4096x4096) and made a smart UV projection of the texture-less model. Then I baked the textures from the textured model into a single image and assigned it to the blank image used as a texture on the second model.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aq2tUT0iyCQ&t=2s) helped a lot.

I'm still working on the export, but I'll post an edit when I have the process pinned down.

EDIT: I ended up exporting to collada. It has an efficient loader in threejs and is easy to work with. Blender has a built in exporter.